# React change array in state array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having issues with cloning arrays.

I get movie list to API , but it is not having 'key'.

so I want to change "ID of API" -> "key of my state"

```
state={
  movies:[]
};
```

and

```
const movieList = axios.get("URL.json"); //It is not having key value
```

and How can I do at "this.setState()" ?

[image]

Sorry for the inexperienced explanation

Comment: Why you want the key property when the response hasn't that too?

Comment: Do you want the new structure to be an array of 
key: number?
instead of id: number?

Comment: A low possibility, but if you want to do this in order to have "keys" for mapping your JSX, you don't need to do this. Use the `id` as your `key` since they are unique. If this is not your intention, then just try to give some more detail in your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce, like this:

```
const movieList = [ {id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}]
const keyMovieList = movieList.reduce((acc,rec)=>[...acc, {key:rec.id}], [])
```

See in the playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s538985

Comment: I think that's the strangest use of reduce I ever saw... Why not use .map if you want to change the structure of each element in the array?
`const keyMovieList = movieList.map(input=> { return {key: input.id} })`